# GoCD: How to define a pipeline's entire workspace as an artifact for the next stage?

Tags: go-cd

Using GoCD, how can I define a stage's entire workspace (as a single artifact) for the next stage? This would highly simplify my setup, in which the second stage needs to fetch many different artifacts from the previous one.

I have tried the following artifact declarations:

1. Artifact source = `.`

This causes an error already during the upload in the first stage:

```
[go] The rule [.] cannot match any resource under [pipelines/mypipeline]
[go] [go] Uploading finished. Failed to upload [.]
```

2. Artifact source = `*`

This does not cause errors, but causes a separate upload for each directory in the root folder, instead of a single artifact of the entire workspace. As a result, I still need to fetch multiple concrete artifacts, instead of one big workspace artifact.

```
[go] Uploading artifacts from /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/mypipeline/.svn to [defaultRoot]
[go] Uploading artifacts from /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/mypipeline/cruise-output to [defaultRoot]
[go] Uploading artifacts from /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/mypipeline/<dir1> to [defaultRoot]
[go] Uploading artifacts from /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/mypipeline/<...> to [defaultRoot]
[go] Uploading artifacts from /var/lib/go-agent/pipelines/mypipeline/<dirN> to [defaultRoot]
```

I could probably zip everything myself with another task and define that as an artifact, but with GoCD already zipping and unzipping on its onw, I thought there must be a simpler solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, just a newbie with [GoCD](https://www.gocd.org/), but having gone through the same pain of trial and error, I'll share the syntax I found to work from my experience. For build artifacts in an **upstream pipeline**:

- Source: `#{BUILD_DIR}/*.whl` - it seems wild card syntax works when defining build artifacts; NOTE: the values between the curly braces `{XXX_XX}` are [pipeline parameters](https://docs.gocd.org/21.2.0/configuration/admin_use_parameters_in_configuration.html).
- Destination: `#{ARTIFACT_DIR}` - I prefer to put all my artifacts in a separate folder as it is easier to fetch. GoCD will zip and transfer the folder and unzip it in the downstream pipeline.

In **downstream pipeline** or another stage in the same pipeline when retrieving artifacts using "Fetch Artifact" task:

- Source: `#{ARTIFACT_DIR}` - I use only the directory name to fetch the entire directory
- Destination `./` - the fetched directory will be extracted in current folder in this case

**NOTE:** The above syntax is for fetching directory of artifacts only where the *Source is a file(Not a directory)* checkbox in the "[Fetch Artifact Task](https://docs.gocd.org/21.2.0/introduction/concepts_in_go.html#fetch_artifact)" is not selected.

I was not able to [fetch artifact files](https://www.gocd.org/getting-started/part-2/#fetching_using_artifacts) when I tried parametrizing a file name with pipeline parameters or environment variables (for example my file artifact contained a dynamically generated version) and I did not find anything in the GoCD documentation or examples suggesting it is possible. The docs have example of downloading a file name that is a constant and does not change.

Please share examples of parametrizing file artifacts if possible or suggested workarounds if possible at all.